# Kml file showing in Google Earth but not in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

I have the following kml file, which is rendered in Google Earth. But when I try the same in Google maps, it shows nothing. What could be the possible reason for this? Is this type of file not displayed in Google maps?

Thank you.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

      <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

       <Document>

               <name>Data from a local source.</name>

                <Region>
                    <Lod><minLodPixels>2</minLodPixels></Lod>
                    <LatLonAltBox>
                          <west>75.2971420288086</west>
                          <east>154.70285034179688</east>
                          <south>-11.705361366271973</south>
                          <north>30.36050796508789</north>
                    </LatLonAltBox>
                </Region>

                <GroundOverlay>
                    <drawOrder>1</drawOrder>
                    <Icon>
                          <href>http://www.rimes.int/files/image.png</href>
                    </Icon>
                    <LatLonBox>
                          <west>75.2971420288086</west>
                          <east>154.70285034179688</east>
                          <south>-11.705361366271973</south>
                          <north>30.36050796508789</north>
                    </LatLonBox>
                </GroundOverlay>

       </Document>
  </kml>
```

The code I am using is as follows.

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('map'), 
            {
                zoom: 2,
                center: {lat: 7.794106, lng: 80.677808}
            });


        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://www.rimes.int/files/erddap_kml.kml',
          //url: 'http://www.rimes.int/files/new-new-2.kml',

          map: map
        });

  }

</script>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

This code is working for another kml file (commented 'url'), which is different from the file mentioned above: instead of using an image  overlay, it overlays based on the co-ordinates and fill styles.

What could I be possibly doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: How are you trying to display it with "Google Maps"?

Comment: I am using Google Maps JavaScript API to show it 
(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/kml)

If I use other kml files that has <Placemark> tags, then its showing. However, the one I have posted (uses <Icon>) is not being displayed.

Comment: The posted file works with the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160718.kml).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip Since, you said it was working for you, so I am doubtful if my html file is incorrect. I have shared my file here. [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=90801421058220884642) 

When I use the kml file that I mentioned earlier, its not working. However, if I use another kml file (commented out in the file), its working. Could you please find out what am i doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide any information required to answer your question in the question itself (preferably a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), not in external links.

Comment: @geocodezip I have edited the question.

Comment: [Your "non-working" kml still works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.rimes.int/files/erddap_kml.kml), as does the [code you posted in your question](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jhoq6dhp/), please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

KML is not supported in Google Maps

https://developers.google.com/maps/support/kmlmaps